# sqlalchemy ArgumentError: Textual SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

ArgumentError raises when passing plain text to "order_by".
I'ts occurs with version 0.9.8, but not with version < 0.9.8 or > 0.9.8.

```
q = session.query(Person)
q.order_by('RAND()')
>> ArgumentError: Textual SQL expression 'RAND()' should be explicitly declared as text('RAND()')
```

questions:
1. Is there any official documentation about it?
2. With new versions, is this a good practice to pass plain text, or it is better to wrap it with text()?
3. Is this error raises with more functions other then order_by?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question was about the difference between sqlalchemy versions, and the right way to pass text to order_by. The option to use func.rand or text("RAND()") are well known.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on any of 0.9.7, 0.9.8, or 0.9.9.  Wrapping such constructs with `text()` is required since [1.3](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_13.html#coercion-of-string-sql-fragments-to-text-fully-removed).